# Merging PDF Files in-between another PDF File in java using IText or PDFBox

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I have two PDF files A and B, I have a requirement where i need to Merge both these PDF files based on a condition.Like,If i find a string like "attach PDF" in my A, i have to merge the B file into A from that particular page in A.  For Example,If i spot the word in Page No 3 in my A file I need to merge the B file from Page No:3. I'm using I-Text 5.5.10. Is it possible to achieve this in I-Text or PDFBox. Here is what i have tried as of now.

```
  public static void mergePdf() throws IOException, DocumentException 
{
    PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader("C:\\Users\\user1\\Downloads\\generatedSample.pdf");
    PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader("C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\sample1.pdf");
    Document document = new Document();
    document.addHeader("Header Text", "");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\user1\\Downloads\\MergeFile.pdf");
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, fos);
    document.open();
    PdfImportedPage page;
    PdfCopy.PageStamp stamp;
    Phrase phrase;
    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont();
    Font font = new Font(bf, 9);
    int n = reader1.getNumberOfPages();

    for (int i = 1; i <= reader1.getNumberOfPages(); i++) 
    {
        page = copy.getImportedPage(reader1, i);
        stamp = copy.createPageStamp(page);
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(stamp.getOverContent(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, null, 520, 5, 0);
        stamp.alterContents();
        copy.addPage(page);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= reader2.getNumberOfPages(); i++) 
    {
        page = copy.getImportedPage(reader2, i);
        stamp = copy.createPageStamp(page);
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(stamp.getOverContent(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, null, 520, 5, 0);
        stamp.alterContents();
        copy.addPage(page);
    }
    document.close();
    reader1.close();
    reader2.close();
}
```

Thanks for the solution in advance !!

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Sure !!

Comment: Start with a first step, search for *strings like "attach PDF" in your A* using text extraction applied to *A*. If you find such strings in the extracted text of some page, you know where to add the pages from *B* instead of at the end as your code currently does.

Comment: Combined questions are kindof annoying because it complicates things. Both itext and PDFBox can extract texts and merge PDFs. So ask about one or both of these two in separate questions.